# Non-relational db, which one is the right choice

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, cassandra, redis, non-relational-database

Which Non-relational database should I choose(I know the question is a subjective one and involves taking into consideration the demands of the system).

I read this article [cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis), but still couldn't decide.

It would be really good if the experienced guys here could throw some light on the key points to consider while making this decision.

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that a few points in that article about MongoDB are out of date. Replica sets are preferred over master/slave replication. Replica sets provide auto-failover in case a node fails for some reason. 1.8 provides journaling, eliminating the need to run a full repair after a crash. MongoDB also provides map/reduce (the article seems to imply it doesn't).

Comment: Just as a side note.  I know "non-relational database" is a common colloquialism today, but its a complete misnomer.  The data is completely relational.  If it was truly non-relational then it could not contain key-value pairs.  I believe the more "correct" term for this is NoSchema database.  To drive home the point:  Google App Engine, ext.db, commonly referred to as a "non-relational" database allows for reference properties... which is relational ;)  Its just schemaless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every type of database is very good at something, and cannot stand against the other at something. It is impossible to say which is the best in all the fields... otherwise there would not be reasons for other to exist.

I feel sometime that choices are made on personal feelings about which one is closer to the programmer's way of thinking.

If you specify which are your requirements and your scenario, a better answer can be made.

For example MongoDB and Redis are complementary, they solve different problems and can be (and are) used together to maximize performance. No one beats cassandra on scalability, but it is not so flexible in the schema. CouchDB has an internal "application logic" which is great, but you have to change your mind and learn to speak in json.